# Dynamic Generation Of IF Statements For Concatenation

Tags: java

I'm looking for a flexible/generic way to build up conditions using metadata stored in a Database and then validate incoming requests at runtime 
against the conditions and concatenate value(s) if the condition is met.

My use case looks something like this:

1) A business user selects an operation from a UI i.e. (IF condition from a dropdown), then selects an appropraite field to evaluate i.e. ("language")
   then selects a value for the condition i.e. "Java" followed by some values to concatenate i.e "Java 9" and "is coming soon!"

2) This metaData will get stored in a Database (lets say as a List for the moment) i.e `["language","Java","Java 9","is coming soon"]`
   When my application starts I want to build the appropriate concatenation conditions:

```
private String concatenateString(String condition, String conditionValue, String concatValue1, String concatValue2){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (condition.equals(conditionValue)){
            sb.append(concatValue1);
            sb.append(concatValue2);    
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

3) so at runtime when I receieve a request, i want to compare the values on my incoming request to the various conditions that got built at start up:

```
if language == "Java" then the output would look like => "Java 9 is coming soon"
```

While the above might work for 2 String concatenations, how can achieve the same for a variable number of conditions and concatenation values.

Answer (score 0):

So you want user to create a program by selecting options from a GUI which will be stored in a DB. When the options are read back from the DB you want to parse this into a compileable program and run it?

Use StringBuilder to build a string of the code from the data gotten back from the DB, something like this:

"if (language == '"Java"') { doSomething() }" (you'll need to take care to escape strings inside your string if you are storing strings in the DB.

You can then use Compiler class to compile the string to a program which yo can run (all in runtime, google dynamically compiling c# at runtime).

However, you'll probably want to question why you are thinking of going down that route... I've been there before, dynamic compilation has a very narrow use case.

You could, for instance, create a Dictionary which maps selected languages to some output string and simply use this to get your output like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> langaugeOutputMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
languageOutputMap.Put("Java", "Java9 is coming soon");

private string concatString(string: userChosenString) {
   if (languageOutputMap.containsKey(userChosenString) {
      return languageOutputMap.getValue(userChosenString);
   }
   return string.Empty()
}
```

If you then want to manage multiple conditions, you could have multiple Dictionaries for each condition type and enumerate them in a collection, iterate over them when given a variable sized set of conditions and make sure that all the conditions evaluate through the use of `containsKey()`.

Also, you can use `params` to specify variable length function arguments like so:

public string manyArgs(params string[] stringArgs) {

}

Also, look at PredicateBuilder:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: yes, essentially a business user will build up a variety of different conditions and concatenations and store these in a DB.  I need to use these conditions at runtime to determine what values I need to concatenate.  Maybe you're right, the dynamic compilation route is not the way to go.  Just wanted to see what my options are!